# SQL using SUM: making two additions in the same statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm not that good at sql so please bear with me.

I have two tables. A 'points' table which contains points and the date (on which the points were scored) and a 'Game' table which contains the date and team name.

I'm trying to find out whether the team name 'Alpha' scored more points in the first half of the year, or the second using only one statement.

If you're using SELECT SUM(point), how can you use one statement to divide the data and do the additions?

So far, I've have:

```
SELECT Game.Date, Tname, SUM(point)
FROM Game
INNER JOIN Points ON Game.Date = Points.Date
WHERE Game.Tname = “Alpha”
GROUP BY Game.Date, Game.Tname
```

This doesn't split up the dates though, and I really don't know where to go from here.

Comment: What's your logic for first and second half of the year?

Answer (score 3):

A conditional `SUM()` would do it:

```
SELECT YEAR(Game.Date), Tname
     , SUM(CASE WHEN QUARTER(Game.Date) <= 2 THEN point END) AS FirstHalf
     , SUM(CASE WHEN QUARTER(Game.Date  >= 3 THEN point END) AS LastHalf
FROM Game
INNER JOIN Points ON Game.Date = Points.Date
WHERE Game.Tname = “Alpha”
GROUP BY YEAR(Game.Date), Game.Tname
```

Edit:  You'd probably want to either specify a year or group by year, but the basic idea of the conditional `SUM()` is the important part here.

Answer (score 1):

Your join was messed up... you were going to the same column on the same table. game.Date = game.Date. Assuming that's a mistake as it will create a cross join/Cartesian product. Also, I'm more of a MS SQL guy, but I believe you are looking for this:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN QUARTER(Game.Date) < 3
         THEN "FirstHalfOfYear"
         ELSE "SecondHalfOfYear"
    END AS YearHalf,
    Tname,
    SUM(point) AS TotalPoints
FROM Game
INNER JOIN Points
    ON Points.Date = Game.Date
WHERE Game.Tname = "Alpha"
GROUP BY 
    CASE WHEN QUARTER(Game.Date) < 3
         THEN "FirstHalfOfYear"
         ELSE "SecondHalfOfYear"
    END, Game.Tname
```

Comment: Until a few minutes ago, I couldn't comment. Maybe I should have said "I'd comment, but didn't have enough rep."

:)

Pretty much the only option for new users here is to say something about why your answer is better and others are not. Otherwise, I wouldn't have even provided an answer, would have just commented on yours.

Also, that is a good point. I should have grouped by year.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be simply this what you want. This will sum all the points for Alpha per date.

```
SELECT Game.Date, SUM(point)
FROM Game
INNER JOIN Points ON Game.Date = Points.Date
WHERE Game.Tname = “Alpha”
GROUP BY Game.Date
```

Comment: Why would you expect removing `TName` to help?

Answer (score 0):

I expect a lot of your problem is here:

```
INNER JOIN Points ON Game.Date = Game.Date
```

I think this should be

```
INNER JOIN Points ON Game.Date = Points.Date
```

Comment: Sorry, that was just a typo.